# Passing a JS object as a React props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am taking a React course and we are asked to pass a single JavaScript object as props to a React app. Below is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


const App = ( ) => {
    const course = {
        name: 'Half Stack application development',
        parts: [
            {
            name: 'Fundamentals of React',
            exercises: 10
            },
            {
            name: 'Using props to pass data',
            exercises: 7
            },
            {
            name: 'State of a component',
            exercises: 14
            }
        ]
    }
    const Header = ( ) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{course.name}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
    const Content = ( ) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <Part name={course.parts} exercises={course.parts} />
                <Part name={course.parts} exercises={course.parts} />
                <Part name={course.parts} exercises={course.parts} />
            </div>
        )
    }
    const Part = ( ) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{course.parts} {course.parts}</p> 
            </div>
        )
    }
    const Total = () => {

        return (
            <div>
                <p>Number of exercises {course.parts + course.parts + course.parts}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Header course={{course}} />
            <Content course={course} />
            <Total course={course} />
        </div>
    )
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

It is returning an error --> Objects are not valid as a React child.

I couldn't use *this* with the arrow function. I tried *props* but couldn't fix it. Please can someone help me to refactor and fix my code.

Comment: your content component seems to be empty.

Comment: I was editing it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? you are passing course as a prop  but not receiving it in your Header, Content or Total component. Also, course.parts is an array you can not print an array in your part component without mapping over it.

Comment: This is my problem. I want to access the parts of the course object, but I don't know how. I am new to React

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code that should work as desired: [Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-zhukovsky-knm9d?file=/src/App.js). Your `course.parts` is an array and that is one of the reasons why some errors occured. However, there were some more problems related to props and I would suggest reading [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

You can also avoid hard-coded values in Content component by using map() function:

```
const Content = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        {course.parts.map(singlePart => {
          return <Part singlePart={singlePart} />;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Many useful array functions are described [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/es6/es6_arrays.htm).

Comment: Thanks @patryk-szwed

Comment: Thank you very much @patryk-szwed. I really liked your code, with the way you destructured Part to SinglePart after that the code was really clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Props this way:

```
const App = ( ) => {
    const course = {
        name: 'Half Stack application development',
        parts: [
            {
            name: 'Fundamentals of React',
            exercises: 10
            },
            {
            name: 'Using props to pass data',
            exercises: 7
            },
            {
            name: 'State of a component',
            exercises: 14
            }
        ]
    }
    const Header = ({course}) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{course.name}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
    const Content = ({course}) => {
        //use parts.map(el => <Part part={el}) instead
        return (
            <div>
                <Part part={course.parts[0]} />
                <Part part={course.parts[1]}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
    const Part = ({part}) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{part.name} {part.exercises}</p> 
            </div>
        )
    }
    const Total = ({course}) => {
        // dont forget to refactor counting exercises with reduce function or something prettier
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Number of exercises {course.parts[0].exercises + course.parts[1].exercises + course.parts[2].exercises}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Header course={course} />
            <Content course={course} />
            <Total course={course} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Also, you could have problem with

```
  <Header course={{course}} />
```

because you pass Object {course: {name: '...', parts: [...]}} as props, not {name: '..', parts: [..]}

Finally, you can move out your Header, Content, Total components from App component.

Comment: Thanks @Nikita Slupko.